# How do I get the value of a text field and output it in a string?

Tags: objective-c

Here is the code:

```
-(IBAction)customButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *text = Field.text;
    //label is called Label
}
```

How can I get the value of the UITextField (Field) and set it to the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by value you mean the `UITextField`'s text, you can the text of the label with `setText`:

```
[Label setText: text]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[Label setText:[Field text]]